# Create new workflow history list in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am new to workflows, can someone please tell me how to create new workflow history list in Office 365.

I do not want log history of different workflows in same history list.
I am using Nintex App to create workflows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is from within SharePoint Designer.

Once you create a new workflow, navigate to the Workflow Settings page. Look for the History List option under Settings, you will see a dropdown box. It will be defaulted to Workflow History, but if you click on the dropdown, it gives you the option for New History List.

[image]

**Note:** It is recommended to do this initially when the workflow is created. You will see a warning box that changing the associated history list may break list references. I believe this only affects logging messages to the Workflow History List, but I haven't tested it enough to know for sure.

Also, the Workflow History lists are hidden under site contents. You will likely not see this list if you look under site contents for your site.

If you need access to this list directly, there is a link on the Workflow Settings page in Designer that will give you the full url for the list, but it will be accessible via `site/subsite/Lists/ListName` just like any other list on your site would be. Designer will generate a name for the History List based on the name of your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was really helpful

Comment: No problem @user31823 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: how on earth can you create history list for 'Nintex' workflow using SharePoint designer?? i am confused.